# Adding Optional header in http request in zephyr OS(using nRF9160DK)

Tags: http-headers, zephyr-rtos

I try to put optional header in my http request, based on zephyr OS.
I'm trying to use optional_header in zephyr OS, but it didn't work well.

I tried like this.
Here is my requesting function and structure of headers

```
const char *http_header_val[][2] = {
    {"Content-type", "application//json"},
    {"Accept", "application//json"},
    {"Iccid", "8944501201210634639"},
    {"ModemId", "860016042571781"},
    {"Timestamp", "20231109113230"},
    {"ZoneOffset", "+9"}
};
```

```
int send_request()
{
    struct http_request req = {0};

    const char *h_dd = "IccId";

    req.method = HTTP_POST;
    req.url = "/TEST";
    req.host = SERVER_HOSTNAME;
    req.port = SERVER_PORT;
    req.protocol = "HTTP/1.1";
    req.recv_buf = recv_buf;
    req.recv_buf_len = sizeof(recv_buf);
    req.response = response_cb;
    req.optional_headers = http_header_val;
    
    int err = http_client_req(sock4, &req, timeout, NULL);
    //LOG_INF("HEADER \n\n\r%s", (req.header_fields));
    return err;
}

/* press button for send request to server*/
static void button_handler(uint32_t button_state, uint32_t has_changed)
{
    switch (has_changed) {
    
    case DK_BTN1_MSK:
    /* send http request */
    
        if(button_state & DK_BTN1_MSK){
            
            int err_2 = send_request();

            if(err_2 <= 0){
                LOG_INF("Failed to send message, %d", errno);
                LOG_INF("Failed request, %d", err_2);
                break;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

This is my response callback function.

```
static void response_cb(struct http_response *rsp, enum http_final_call final_data, void *user_data)
{
    if(rsp->http_status_code >= 200 && rsp->http_status_code < 300){
        LOG_INF("Net status code: %d", rsp->http_status_code);
        LOG_INF("Net status: %s", rsp->http_status);
        LOG_INF("Get data size: %d", rsp->recv_buf_len);
        LOG_INF("Get data : \n\r%s", rsp->recv_buf);
    }else{
        LOG_ERR("Net status code: %d", rsp->http_status_code);
        LOG_ERR("Net status: %s", rsp->http_status);
        LOG_INF("Get data : \n\r%s", rsp->recv_buf);
    }
}
```

and this is my result

```
*** Booting nRF Connect SDK v2.5.0 ***
[00:00:00.398,986] <inf> Socket_tel: Initializing modem library
[00:00:00.638,885] <inf> Socket_tel: Connecting to LTE network
[00:00:02.226,013] <inf> Socket_tel: RRC mode: Connected
[00:00:03.360,443] <inf> Socket_tel: Network registration status: Connected - roaming
[00:00:03.360,595] <inf> Socket_tel: Connected to LTE network
[00:00:03.891,815] <inf> Socket_tel: IPv4 Address found 34.198.21.227
[00:00:04.434,509] <inf> Socket_tel: Successfully connected to server
[00:00:04.434,539] <inf> Socket_tel: Press button 1 on your DK to send your message
[00:00:04.434,539] <inf> Socket_tel: Response
[00:00:09.440,399] <err> Socket_tel: Net status code: 400
[00:00:09.440,460] <err> Socket_tel: Net status: Bad Request
[00:00:09.440,551] <inf> Socket_tel: Get data : 
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: awselb/2.0
Date: Fri, 10 Nov 2023 01:35:17 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 122
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

I think my problem is adding http header but I don't know how to solve that.

Any kind of your help, very helpful to me.

thank you.

ddyd.

Comment: Have you tried to simply add a ":" to your header keys?  Otherwise your example looks correct.